# RxCpp: Difference bewteen schedulers

Tags: c++, reactivex, rxcpp

For the different kind of coordination that uses a particular scheduler as described [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxCpp/blob/main/DeveloperManual.md). The available types are:

```
identity_immediate()
identity_current_thread()
identity_same_worker(worker w)
serialize_event_loop()
serialize_new_thread()
serialize_same_worker(worker w)
observe_on_event_loop()
observe_on_new_thread()
```

Could anyone help to explain what is the difference between the identity_xxx, serialize_xxx and observe_on_xxx, and when shall each type be used?

Answer (score 0):

- `identity_` - it means no synchronization at all. No mutexes or
  whatever like this. So, it means:

  - `identity_immediate` - would emit the item immmediately with no scheduler at all
  - `identity_current_thread` - would schedule emission to the current thread without any syncrhonization (but it is thread local, so, it doesn't need it)
- `observe_on_` - uses a queue-based scheduler. It uses the queue to "serialize" emissions by enqueueing emissions from one thread and then processing this queue from another:

  - `observe_on_new_thread` - place emission to the queue and process them from a newly created thread
  - `observe_on_event_loop` - same as before, but it uses a thread pool under the hood
- `serialize_` - use mutexes to provide syncrhonization